# How often do Collection Points respawn?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In Xenoblade Chronicles 2 you can get items from glowing Collection Point orbs. How often do these Collection Points respawn?

[image: Rex looking at a collection point]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the Xenoblade wiki](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Collection_Point), Collection Points reset after using Skip Travel. I confirmed this myself with the two collection points next to the Goldmouth Flight Deck in Argentum. I've also seen collection points respawn after cutscenes.